# How to use Method param as variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello i have a problem in ruby mine it says that my param isn't initialized can you help me? I need to sum all the subjects

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :english, :math, :science, :french, :pe

  def initialize(name, english, math, science, french, pe)
    @name = name
    @english = english
    @math = math
    @science = science
    @french = french
    @pe = pe
  end

  def avg_sum_grades(param)
    sum_of_subjcet_grades = students.map { |student| student.param }
  end

students = [
  student.new('brian', 3, 4, 5, 5, 6),
  student.new('eric', 1, 3, 4, 5, 2),
  student.new('jessica', 2, 1, 4, 5, 3),
  student.new('agatha', 4, 4, 5, 3, 5),
  student.new('alex', 2, 4, 5, 2, 5)
]

avg_sum_grades("english")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us how you are using this method in your code.

Comment: I'm seeing a bunch of issues. You have class `Student` with no `end` and then you're trying to create new instances of `student` rather than `Student`.

Comment: If you write something like `a.b`, the `b` must be the name of a method known to `a`. In your case, a `student` does not have a method named `param`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a method based on a *name* passed into a method.

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :english, :math, :science, :french, :pe

  def initialize(name, english, math, science, french, pe)
    @name = name
    @english = english
    @math = math
    @science = science
    @french = french
    @pe = pe
  end
end
```

This is definitely possible by using a symbol with the `#send` method.

```
bob = Student.new("Bob", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
bob.send(:pe)
# => 5
```

You're trying to do this on a group of `Student` objects.

```
students = [
  student.new('brian', 3, 4, 5, 5, 6),
  student.new('eric', 1, 3, 4, 5, 2),
  student.new('jessica', 2, 1, 4, 5, 3),
  student.new('agatha', 4, 4, 5, 3, 5),
  student.new('alex', 2, 4, 5, 2, 5)
]
```

So you could write:

```
def get_avg_grade(students, subject)
  grades = students.map { |s| s.send(subject) }
  grades.sum / grades.length
end
```

Which can be called: `get_avg_grade(students, :math)`.

*One more thing...*

Given that you are just creating accessors for everything, you can really just write:

```
Student = Struct.new(:name, :english, :math, :science, :french, :pe)
```

Comment: Likely flagged as no longer needed as I incorporated your feedback into an edit. Thanks for that, by the way!

Comment: I was referring to, for example, `student.new('brian', 3, 4, 5, 5, 6)`, which is what the OP had written. You might point out that it needs to be `Student.new('brian', 3, 4, 5, 5, 6)`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer's distinguishing characteristic is that it does not require all students to have taken the same courses.

I have in mind the following example to create an instance of the class `Student`:

```
Student.new('eric', english: 1, math: 3, french: 5, pe: 2),
```

Notice that Eric has not been enrolled in science.

---

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :grades
  def initialize(name, **grades)
    @name = name
    @grades = grades
  end
end
```

```
def avg_grade(students, subject)
  avg(students.filter_map do |student|
    student.grades[subject] if student.grades.key?(subject)
  end)
end
```

```
def avg(arr)
  arr.sum.fdiv(arr.size).round(1)
end
```

See [Double-Splat](https://medium.com/@sologoubalex/parameter-with-double-splat-operator-in-ruby-d944d234de34), [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) and [Numeric#fdiv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv) and [Numeric#round](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-round).

---

Let's create some students.

```
students = [
  Student.new('brian', english: 3, math: 4, science: 5, french: 5, pe: 6),
  Student.new('eric', english: 1, math: 3, french: 5, pe: 2),
  Student.new('jessica', math: 1, science: 4, french: 5, pe: 3),
  Student.new('agatha', english: 4, science: 5, french: 3, pe: 5),
  Student.new('alex', english: 2, math: 4, french: 2, pe: 5)
]
```

Let's see what we have.

```
students.each { |student| puts "@name = #{student.name}, @grades = #{student.grades}" }
@name = brian, @grades = {:english=>3, :math=>4, :science=>5, :french=>5, :pe=>6}
@name = eric, @grades = {:english=>1, :math=>3, :french=>5, :pe=>2}
@name = jessica, @grades = {:math=>1, :science=>4, :french=>5, :pe=>3}
@name = agatha, @grades = {:english=>4, :science=>5, :french=>3, :pe=>5}
@name = alex, @grades = {:english=>2, :math=>4, :french=>2, :pe=>5}
```

---

Now compute average grades by subject. To do that we first construct an array of all subjects taken by at least one student:

```
subjects = students.reduce([]) { |subs, student| subs | student.grades.keys }
  #=> [:english, :math, :science, :french, :pe]
```

and then display the average grades by subject:

```
subjects.each { |subject| puts "#{subject}: #{avg_grade(students, subject)}" }
english: 2.5
math: 3.0
science: 4.7
french: 4.0
pe: 4.2
```

See [Array#|](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-7C).

---

Even if all students take the same five subjects it could be argued that

```
Student.new('brian', english: 3, math: 4, science: 5, french: 5, pe: 6)
```

would tend to be less error-prone than

```
Student.new('brian', 3, 4, 5, 5, 6)
```

where it is understood that the grades are for English, math, science, French and PE, respectively. Of course, if the grades are being provided in this format from an external source there would be no choice on how the arguments are to be expressed.

Answer (score -1):

You will need the `instance_variable_get` to get the instance variable as string.

```js
class Student
    attr_accessor :name, :english, :math, :science, :french, :pe

    def initialize(name, english, math, science, french, pe)
      @name = name
      @english = english
      @math = math
      @science = science
      @french = french
      @pe = pe
    end 
 end

@students = [
  Student.new('brian', 3, 4, 5, 5, 6),
  Student.new('eric', 1, 3, 4, 5, 2),
  Student.new('jessica', 2, 1, 4, 5, 3),
  Student.new('agatha', 4, 4, 5, 3, 5),
  Student.new('alex', 2, 4, 5, 2, 5)
]

  def avg_sum_grades(param)
       sum_of_subjcet_grades = @students.sum{ |student| student.instance_variable_get("@#{param}") }
  end

avg_sum_grades("english")
```

Comment: Given that accessor methods have been created for all instance variables, there is no need to use `instance_variable_get`.

Comment: But does using the instance_variable_get does not mean it is wrong. It just another way of accomplishing the require task. why then the down vote.